# Unbale to Interact with elements using QAFWebDriver for Android Mobile Web in Perfecto

Tags: android, mobile-website, appium-android, qaf, perfecto

Below are the details:

Selenium - 4.11.0
Appium Java-Client - 8.5.1
QAF - 4.0.0-RC2
OpenJDK 17

perfecto.properties

driver.name=perfectoDriver
remote.server=https://.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub/fast
remote.port=80
perfecto.additional.capabilities={"perfecto:options":{"automationName":"Appium","orientation":"LANDSCAPE","javascriptEnabled":true,
"unicodeKeyboard":true,"deviceName":"R52T509SH3P","browserName":"Chrome",
"securityToken":""},"driverClass":"io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver"}

we have tried with:

```
QAFWebDriver driver =  new BancaTestBasePage().getTestBase().getDriver();
    driver.findElement(By.name("OpeId")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='IMAGE']")).click();
```

expecting to enter user name and password and click login button

Actual: Error : org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function

Logs:

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function
(Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.61)
(Driver info: chromedriver=117.0.5938.149 (e3344ddefa12e60436fa28c81cf207c1afb4d0a9-refs/branch-heads/5938@{#1539}),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver
Command: [186fc2c3-1e03-4fba-a70f-9aa18f524856, executeScript {args=[{element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=A659E8FAF0A90B4AB694F72551EFAF0E_element_12}], script=arguments[0].scrollIntoView();}]
Capabilities {appium:accessToken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI..., appium:app: , appium:appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appium:appPackage: com.android.chrome, appium:assert_javascript_enabled: true, appium:audioStreamInfo: {"audioStreamingServerUrl":..., appium:automationName: Appium, appium:chromedriverChromeMappingFile: C:\nexperience\modules\Chro..., appium:chromedriverExecutableDir: C:\nexperience\modules\Chro..., appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {automationName: Appium, browserName: Chrome, chromedriverChromeMappingFile: C:\nexperience\modules\Chro..., chromedriverExecutableDir: C:\nexperience\modules\Chro..., deviceName: R52T509SH3P, driverClass: io.appium.java_client.andro..., goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: [], w3c: false}, javascriptEnabled: true, orientation: LANDSCAPE, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 12, unicodeKeyboard: true}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 31, appium:deviceManufacturer: samsung, appium:deviceModel: SM-X800, appium:deviceName: R52T509SH3P, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 340, appium:deviceScreenSize: 2800x1752, appium:deviceSessionId: 186fc2c3-1e03-4fba-a70f-9aa..., appium:deviceUDID: R52T509SH3P, appium:driverClass: io.appium.java_client.andro..., appium:entityType: remote_web_driver, appium:executionId: 186fc2c3-1e03-4fba-a70f-9aa..., appium:host: cloud.perfectomobile.com, appium:internalPureAppiumFlow: true, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:liveStreamEnabled: false, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:mcmExecutionId: charitha.lebaka@cloud.co...., appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:orientation: LANDSCAPE, appium:password: , appium:pixelRatio: 2.125, appium:platformVersion: 12, appium:reportPdfUrl: https://cloud.app.perfect..., appium:scriptName: RemoteWebDriver, appium:securityToken: , appium:serverConnector: , appium:statBarHeight: 51, appium:stopUrl: https://cloud.perfectomob..., appium:streamInfo: {"url":"wss://ams-01.perfec..., appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:testGridReportUrl: https://cloud.app.perfect..., appium:testRunWithPureAppiumFlow: true, appium:unicodeKeyboard: true, appium:viewportRect: {height: 1599, left: 0, top: 51, width: 2800}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, browserName: Chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: [], w3c: false}, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: 186fc2c3-1e03-4fba-a70f-9aa18f524856
at .Given the user login with credential(scenarios/E2E/e2e.feature:10)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.executeSuper(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:237)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.executeWithoutLog(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:254)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.executeWitoutLog(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:299)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.execute(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:277)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.execute(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:231)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.executeScript(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:1251)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementMetaDataListener.scrollToElement(ElementMetaDataListener.java:187)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementMetaDataListener.onFailure(ElementMetaDataListener.java:181)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.onFailure(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:540)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.execute(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:276)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.execute(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:111)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.sendKeys(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:242)
at jp.co.cloud.ui.pages.LoginPage.Login(LoginPage.java:47)
at jp.co.cloud.steps.IllustrationSingleSteps.inputsIDAndPasswordThenLogin(IllustrationSingleSteps.java:40)
at jp.co.cloud.steps.CommonSteps.loginWithCredential(CommonSteps.java:44)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:150)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:149)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:128)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario.scenario(DataDrivenScenario.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have configured global element meta-data to specify [auto scroll behavior](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html#self-descriptive-locator) using `scroll` meta-key or using custom listener.

If you have any custom element listener(s) look into it.

If not, either check if you have configured `element.default.metadata` [property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html) to update it accordingly or set `element.default.listener` to `false`. To disable scroll you can remove `scroll` meta-data or set it to `false`. Make sure your changes takes effect, refer different ways of [setting properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html).